# Netbeans 7: How to unwrap long lines of code and editor context-menu "Format"

Tags: java, netbeans

By default, the line length in Netbeans is 80 characters.
I increased it up to 120.

Then I see, Tools->Options->Editor->Formatting->[Language:Java, Category:Wrapping] :: almost all the values are set to : Never [ never to wrap ].

Then I tried to reformat the java code using the Format context menu of the Netbeans editor window.
I expected Netbeans to reformat this piece of code

```
                out.println(
                        amount + " dollars are "
                        + yenAmount.toPlainString() + " yen.");
                out.println(
                        yenAmount.toPlainString() + " yen are "
                        + euroAmount.toPlainString() + " Euro.");
```

into something like that:

```
                out.println(amount + " dollars are " + yenAmount.toPlainString() + "yen.");
                out.println(yenAmount.toPlainString() + " yen are " + euroAmount.toPlainString() + " Euro.");
```

Yet it did not happen.
It leaves the wrapped lines as they are.
Eclipse in this case would unwrap those lines if you reformat the code.

Is there any way to format the code in Netbeans as Eclipse does, at least to unwrap all the wrapped lines into long ones in a few clicks ?

Comment: Not sure if this is feasible. The positive side is that if you wrap lines on purpose to show the logic of your code, Netbeans will not change the layout.

Comment: @assylias I agree, but it would have been nice to have an option to keep the layout or reformat completely according to your new formatting settings.

Comment: I am using Netbeans 8 and i encounter same anoying behaviour by not unwrapping line of code to match the max line size defined. Did you find any way to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

I did a regex replace

"\,\n\s*"  with ", "
and 
"\n\s*." with "."

remove double quotes. I added them so space would be visible